# C# dependent property / property coercion

Tags: c#, dependency-properties

I have the following class:

```
public class Numbers :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _Max;
    public double Max 
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Max;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= _Min)
            {
                this._Max = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Max");
            }
        }
    }

    private double _Min;
    public double Min
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Min;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value <= Max)
            {
                this._Min = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Min");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }        
}
```

Problem: I dont want to allow user to enter max value less than min value and so on. But above code is not working for the first time when other class try to set min / max value when min / max value has default value of zero.
Since by default min and max value will be zero, if min value is set > 0 which is logically correct but the constraint is not allowed to do that.
I think I need to solve this using dependent property or coercion. Could anyone guide to do that?

Comment: Why min and max have default of 0? why not Double.MinDouble and Double.MaxDouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could back it by a Nullable so it becomes this:

```
public class Numbers : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double? _Max;
    public double Max
    {
        get
        {
            return _Max ?? 0;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= _Min || !_Max.HasValue)
            {
                this._Max = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Max");
            }
        }
    }

    private double? _Min;
    public double Min
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Min ?? 0;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value <= Max || !_Min.HasValue)
            {
                this._Min = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Min");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested but it is not working as expected. It eventually allows user to enter max value less than min value.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize _Max to Double.MaxValue, _Min to Double.MinValue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand you correctly, but you could have a `private bool` indicating if the value is getting set for the first time and thus overriding the check.

out of my head:

```
    private bool _FirstTimeSet = false;
    private double _Max;
    public double Max 
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Max;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= _Min || _FirstTimeSet == false)
            {
                this._FirstTimeSet = true;
                this._Max = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Max");
            }
        }
    }
```